# datastage buildop error - buildop throwing the error

Tags: datastage

I am getting the following error message, when I am running a job in datastage. The buildop stage is throwing this error

```
    isUsable() is false on the accessor interfacing to field "getEditsReturn"
```

The filed is input field.

getEditsReturn is the only input column to buildop.

The code is

```
   while(!inputDone(0)){

       readRecord(0);

       input = inputData.getEditsReturn;

       fprintf(fp,"input : %s",input.c_str());

        //break the string based on delimiter and assign to output columns

       transferAndWriteRecord(0);

       }
```

Here input is the c++ string type(not char[]). I tried to assign the input column to char[] also. It was also not working. I have set autoread and autowrite to false. I am writing those output columns to a file using fprintf. I am getting that output correctly in the file. But the stage is failing

Comment: Server Job or Parallel job?  Can you list what is happening in the job, or what you have added/changed in the job before this error appeared?

Comment: @Damienknight : I am editing the question to add details. I got this error on the first run :-(